# Event handler in angularJS 2

Tags: angular

```
$scope.$on('msg', function(e, msg)
{
    toastr.error("Error. Err-01", "Invalid Login!");

});
```

This is event handler function in angular 1.How can I convert in to angular 2?

Comment: What event is `msg`? There are different ways in Angular2 but there is no direct translation from your code. There is no `$scope` anymore. What problem do you actually try to solve. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

Events are now defined on components themselves. There is no more concept of scope in Angular2...

You can attach handlers on them from the HTML elements:

```
<my-component (someEvent)="handleEvent($event.value)"></my-component>
```

or within JavaScript code:

```
this.myEventEmitter.subscribe(
  ...
)
```

Defining the `myEventEmitter` can be done within a component that way:

```
@Component({
  (...)
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  @Output()
  myEventEmitter: EventEmitter;

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    this.myEventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  }

  select(value) {
    this.myEventEmitter.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: EvenEmitter is just fine and seems to be replacing the $on('event') part. But how to use toastr's different methods in TS as they are written in Javascript? I guess toastr.success(),toastr.error() would just not work as expected.